# Why can't I install macOS Big Sur on my system?

Tags: macos, big-sur

I have tried installing macOS Big Sur on my system but I am getting the following error message:

[image: macOS Big Sur install problem]

I have tried disabling Gatekeeper but it makes no difference.

Comment: Which Mac do you have, from which version are you upgrading, did you try deleting the installer and downloading it again?

Comment: ...And this is all assuming you are upgrading using System Preferences > Software Update? And not from something you downloaded elsewhere?